# Oracle Client issue with TNS Listener when using EZconnect (ORA:12541)

Tags: c#, oracle, deployment

I have installed `Oracle 11g`, after that `ODAC x64` and after that `ODAC x86` (to get ODT) and successfully ran `Oracle 11g` and `Oracle Data Provider x64` for my C# project that uses Oracle in backend.

I used `EZconnect` naming method to connect to the Oracle database. I followed some deployment instructions from [Stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com), whereby I copied 4 or 5 dlls into the directory of the executable as suggested.

Although the program on the target machine can detect the `Oracle Data Provider` as well as `Oracle Client`, it gives error `ORA:12541 No TNS listener`. Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listener runs on the database server-- you need a listener in order to establish a connection to the database from any remote client.  It is completely unrelated to the client configuration and how the client is configured to resolve a TNS alias.

Are you sure that the listener is running and that you're trying to connect to the proper machine on the proper port?  The error implies that you're connecting to the wrong machine. that you're connecting on the wrong port, that you've specified the wrong service name, or that the listener for the database is down.  The first three would be errors in the client configuration.  The last one would mean that the problem is on the server.

Comment: Sir, from your 1st paragraph, I configured that the target machine will be both client as well as the server. right? If it is so then at the target machine, how can I start listener service with help of oci.dll, oraocci11.dll, oraops11w.dll, oracle.dataaccess.dll etc. (deployed with project's exe file).

Comment: Also let me clear a thing sir, that May I have to install any type of oracle client/oracle instant client/oracle full setup on every target machine or not ??

Comment: Till far i am thinking that my project will work on every target machine just by using oci.dll, Oracle.DataAccess.dll, oraociei11.dll, OraOps11w.dll, Orannzsbb11.dll, oraocci11.dll, ociw32.dll in the directory of executable.

Comment: @Shivam - You say that you "configured that the target machine will be both client as well as the server".  That seems unlikely.  If you want the target machine to be the server, you would need to have installed an Oracle database on the machine.  That would involve much, much more than installing a handful of DLLs as part of an Oracle Instant Client install which is what it sounds like you want.  The database would be installed on whatever machine your application is configured to connect to.

Comment: I am agree wid u sir. In very clear words i just wanted to install my oracle application on a target machine. This target machine is not connected to any other computer nor connected to the server. Now will the application will run on that machine properly using oracle instant client, oracle data providers and not having any oracle home or oracle server??    if your answer is NO, then how can i achieve this...... thanx

Comment: @Shivam - If you are stating that you want to install your application on a machine and then connect to an Oracle database that is also installed on that machine, you would need to install the Oracle database on that machine in addition to doing the Oracle client install.  You could potentially use the express edition of the database depending on your requirements but that is going to involve much more than installing a handful of DLLs as part of the Oracle Instant Client install.